# What for do we need Code Snippet project in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, code-snippets

I am wondering why we have that option? Do anyone use it? It says:

```
 "Creates a qmake-based project for which a code snippet can be entered."
```

[image: project creator in QtCreator]

Aren't we able to enter code snipped anyway?

In .pro file it look like this:( I have chosen console app)

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT = core
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
test.h
```